# textarea $watch scrollheight and scrolltop does not trigger update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, textarea

I am writing a simple Angular directive which is meant to display line numbers next to a `textarea`. However, for some reason, the $watch expression does not trigger an update. Here's the code:

```
    mod.directive('newTextArea', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          query: '='
        },
        template:
          '<div>' +
          '  <div ng-style="{height: height}" style="width: 20px; float: left; color: gray; font-family: Courier New; font-size: 14px; overflow: hidden; height: 85px; position: relative; top: 5px;">' +
          '    <div style="position: absolute">' +
          '    <span ng-repeat="line in lines">{{line}}<br></span>' +
          '    </div>' +
          '  </div>' +
          '  <textarea id="query-area" style="overflow-x: scroll; font-family: Courier New; font-size: 14px;">' +
          '  </textarea> {{ lines }}' +
          '</div>',
        controller: function($scope, $attrs, $element) {
          var textarea = document.getElementById('query-area');

          function updateLayout() {
              var st = textarea.scrollTop;
              var h = textarea.scrollHeight;
              $scope.height = h;
console.log(st, h);
              if (st !== undefined && h !== undefined) {
                var start = Math.round(st / 14);
                var stop = Math.round((st + h) / 14);
                $scope.lines = _.range(start+1, stop+1);
            }
          }

          $scope.$watch(
            function() {
              return [textarea.scrollHeight, textarea.scrollTop];
            }, updateLayout, true
          );
        }
      };
```

The lines numbers should update as soon as the textarea is scrolled or if its size changes. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watchers are run during the digest loop. Writing in the text area does not cause the digest loop to start, so the watcher will never be executed.

If you for example add `ng-model="something"` to the `textarea` element it will work since then Angular will bind to a bunch of events and internally trigger the digest loop when they fire.

Without relying on something else to trigger the digest loop you can replace the `$watch` with something like this:

```
var listener = function() {
  $scope.$apply(updateLayout);
};

angular.element(textarea).on('keyup keydown keypress change', listener);

updateLayout();

$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
  angular.element(textarea).off('keyup keydown keypress change', listener);
});
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/nIkGyhM75OScU8ZyosyP?p=preview

Comment: Works well for when you change text, but not when you resize the `textarea`. Is there perhaps an event missing?

Comment: These were just example events. Don't think there is a resize event for textarea however, at least not one that is implemented across most browsers. You can add `mouseup` to update when releasing after resize.

Comment: Ok, that'll do. Thanks for your help!